# Error installing azure-iothub-device-client with Python pip

Tags: python, azure, azure-iot-hub

Trying to follow the [tutorial about Azure IoT for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-python-getstarted) I'm failing in the very first step...

Trying to install the Python package, as described in the documentation:

```
pip install azure-iothub-device-client
```

I get this error:

```
Collecting azure-iothub-device-client
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement azure-iothub-device-client (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for azure-iothub-device-client
```

I'm running Python in a virtualenv (named `azure`). Pip and Python version information:

```
(azure)fermin@neodeb:~$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/fermin/src/virtualenvs/azure/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

(azure)fermin@neodeb:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.9
```

Some hint about this problem and its solution? Thanks!

Comment: thank u .. it works

Comment: No... actually it is not working. At least in my setup. If has worked for you, could you elaborate a little bit about how did you make it, please? Thx!

Answer (score 3):

According to the Azure offical tutorial [`Connect your simulated device to your IoT hub using Python`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-python-getstarted), it shows a note about Azure IoTHub SDK for Linux & MacOS as below.

> Note
>
> The pip packages for azure-iothub-service-client and azure-iothub-device-client are currently available only for Windows OS. For Linux/Mac OS, please refer to the Linux and Mac OS-specific sections on the [Prepare your development environment for Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/doc/python-devbox-setup.md) post.

The document [Prepare your development environment for Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/doc/python-devbox-setup.md) is talking about how to build the Azure IoT Hub SDKs for Python on Linux/Mac OS.

Comment: Yes it requires a very specific version of c++ boost library to be installed on the host system. The second option is to build the boost library yourself.

Comment: The link you refer is broken

Answer (score 0):

you should use this command, but no forget to install pip3, in the tutorial that you mention there is a link for that

pip3 install azure-iothub-device-client